# How change Retrofit baseUrl in runtime?

Tags: retrofit2

Android Studio 3.1

Here my Retrofit init:

```
 private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(httpClient.build());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    public static <T> T createRestClient(Class<T> restClientClass) {
        retrofit = builder.build();
        return retrofit.create(restClientClass);
    }

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return retrofit;
    }
```

The **API_BASE_URL** I set in gradle.properties:

```
DEBUG_API_BASE_URL=\"http://myhost.com/\"
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But sometime, e.g. when I run tests, I need to change `baseUrl`.
To do this I change production url in **DEBUG_API_BASE_URL** in file **gradle.properties** to test url.
After finish tests I return production url in file **gradle.properties**.
It's work. But I think it's not good solution.

Is it possible to change in runtime the `baseUrl` for Retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android (unclear from the question), you can use different buildTypes. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips section "Share custom fields and resource values with your app's code"

```
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    release {
      buildConfigField("String", "API_BASE_URL", \"http://www.myhost.com/\")

    }
    debug {

      buildConfigField("String", "API_BASE_URL", \"http://staging.myhost.com/\")    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know about buildType. Is this a best solution for my problem?